# USB HID pen requirements

Tags: windows-vista, usb, driver, hid, pen

Is there a USB HID pen driver in Windows Vista? 
If so, what are the requirements for USB descriptors, in order to make Windows Vista recognize the pen and load the pen driver?

What I'm searching for is the pen equivalent to the HID mouse driver, HID keyboard driver and mass storage driver. The mentioned example drivers makes it possible for Windows, Linux and Mac OS to recognize mouse, keyboard and memory sticks without installing new drivers.

Windows Vista has a lot of native support for pen, and it is possible to define a USB pen device only using standard HID usage tables (from a USB protocol point of view). So far I'm able to make USB HID descriptors that qualify as mouse and keyboard (from OS point of view), and automatically uses the standard driver supplied by the OS.

For my Pen, however, Windows Vista just loads the generic HID driver, and does not realize that the device is a "pen". The motivation for defining a pen rather than a mouse with absolute coordinates, is that Vista supports special features like "gestures", but this is only enabled for Pen/Digitizer devices.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this paper: https://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/input/DigitizerDrvs_touch.mspx

Answer (score 2):

This link helped me a lot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/supporting-usages-in-digitizer-report-descriptors

> Required HID Usages for Digitizers
>
> The following usages are required for all digitizers. Devices that do
> not support all of the required usages will not work on Windows 8:
>
> - X and Y
> - Tip
> - Scan Time (only required for touch devices)
> - In-range
>
> Optional HID Usages:
>
> - Width and Height
> - Confidence
> - Pressure
> - Barrel
> - X Tilt
> - Y Tilt
> - Twist
> - Azimuth